# Convert OLE DB SQL connection string into a dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, connection, pyodbc

I am very new to python and SQL. I have a DB query in Excel which is very large that I am trying to move to Python directly. Currently i read it in from excel using read_excel().

Ive installed import pyodbc and tried to take the connection string from excel and put it into python.

default code that i have written is:

```py
import pyodbc
conn_str = 'Provider.....'
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
                '''SELECT  *        
                FROM [MarketData].[Gas].[KplerVesselHistory]''', conn)
```

The excel connection info is as follows:

```
Connection type: OLE DB Query

Connection string: Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=MarketData;Data Source=FOTDAL02PR;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=[blank];Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False

Command type: SQL
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\bin\pycharm\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: I believe you will find out all the basic to get start with from the package documentation - https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki

Comment: So your Excel document has a query that retrieves rows from a database somewhere and you want to run the equivalent query directly from Python. Is that correct? If so, then it's almost certainly possible. The issue is that pyodbc uses ODBC connections, not OLEDB connections. BTW, you're connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server instance, right?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

This connects using the ODBC driver for SQL Server, runs the query and returns it to Pandas DataFrame and then prints the output.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas


driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
server = 'server_name\instance_name'
database = 'MarketData'
sql = 'SELECT  * FROM [MarketData].[Gas].[KplerVesselHistory]'

conn_str = 'Driver={};Server={};Trusted_Connection=True;Database={}'.format(driver, server, database)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
df = pandas.read_sql(sql, conn)
print(df)
```